# Switch all values in enum

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have an enum and a string, if the string is a certain value I don't care what the enum is as all options are valid. Is there a way to switch all enum values and use `when` on the string? The best I could come up with is an if statement before the switch;

```
if (action == ApiParameterConstants.ActionReturn)
{
    return ApiConstants.HomeDeliveryOrderReturnEndpoint;
}
else
{
    switch (orderType)
    {
        case OrderType.HomeDelivery when action == ApiParameterConstants.ActionAccept:
        case OrderType.DoorToDoor when action == ApiParameterConstants.ActionAccept:
                    return ApiConstants.HomeDeliveryOrderAcceptEndpoint;
        ...
        default:
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Example of what I'm after (I know .All isn't a real thing but you get the idea);

```
switch (orderType)
{
    case OrderType.All when action == ApiParameterConstants.ActionReturn:
        return ApiConstants.HomeDeliveryOrderReturnEndpoint;
    ...
    default:
        return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`Enum.IsDefined`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: Why not check the string first in an `if` block` then you only switch on the enum after that?

Comment: Or use only if/else statement to make it more uniform.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I don't think so unless that can check all values, which I can't seem to see an example of it doing.

Comment: @DavidG - That's what I'm doing currently, wondering if there's an alternative option with the switch.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "check all values"? My understanding was that you wanted to check that `orderType` is a defined value from the enum, but now I'm confused about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you using flags? Are you trying to check if `orderType` has an enum flag? Do you mean to check "if all enum flags are set in this variable"?

Comment: Use the implementation that is the easiest to understand. Your explanation used in your question may give a good hint for an easy to understand implementation.

Comment: If it works, then don't change it. Leave it like it is now, it's readable and simple.

Comment: `case` is checking if `orderType` is a specific value, right? If `action == ApiParameterConstants.ActionReturn` I don't care what `orderType`'s value is - they are all valid. By "check all values" what I mean is how can I `case` to cater for all `orderType` options being valid?

Comment: Why do you need to do `switch` at all? That's what I don't understand here. Are there defined (part of the enum) values that you wish to exclude? If not, why doesn't `Enum.IsDefined` do what you want? It seems like you're just trying to check that someone hasn't gone `OrderType orderType = (OrderType)12345;` and assigned nonsense data to the variable, which is what `Enum.IsDefined` will check.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar - apologies, I misunderstood you initially but I understand your approach now and it makes sense. However, I have tried to implement it as; `                    case Enum.IsDefined(typeof(OrderType), orderType) when action == ApiParameterConstants.ActionReturn:
                        return ApiConstants.OrderCollectEndpoint;` but I get the following errors;

`CS8370: Feature 'recursive patterns' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater` 
`CS0426: The type name 'IsDefined' does not exist in the type 'Enum'`

Comment: CS0426 is odd because it doesn't moan that "IsDefined" doesn't exist until I add it into the `case` so I guess it's probably relating to CS8370.

I'll have a look at increasing the C# language level to get it to work.

Comment: Please see the answer I suggested. The `switch` is really redundant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`Enum.IsDefined`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=net-6.0) to check the value held by `orderType` is a valid enum value:

```cs
if (action == ApiParameterConstants.ActionReturn)
{
    return ApiConstants.HomeDeliveryOrderReturnEndpoint;
}
else if (action == ApiParameterConstants.ActionAccept 
          && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(OrderType), orderType))
{
    return ApiConstants.HomeDeliveryOrderAcceptEndpoint;
}
else
{
    return string.Empty;
}
```

I've removed the `switch` and moved the check to the `else if`, and then moved the `default` action to the `else`.

Comment: Thanks! Per your suggestion I've used `Enum.IsDefined` within the `if` and it works! Only seems to moan if I try to use it within a `case`. I did have to keep the `switch` within the `else` though as in reality there's 70 lines of code in there and I don't want to interfere with it too much (scared of breaking stuff).